# destructure a parameter and keep reference to it too

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a way in ES6 to destructure a parameter and reference it by name as well?

```
myfunction(myparam) {
    const {myprop} = myparam;
    ...
}
```

Can this be done in a single line in the function parameter list? Something similar to Haskell's `@` in pattern matching.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't.

Comment: You are destructuring `myparam` and you can still access it, right? I don't get the question.

Comment: yes. I am asking about the syntax. I know how to accomplish what I need using various ways. I just was wondering if this can be done in a single line.

Comment: @thefourtheye: Something like `myfunction(obj@{myprop})`. You can do this in LiveScript like `f = ({myprop}:obj)` for example.

Comment: @elclanrs Ah okay. Got it now. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no syntax support for this. I guess you could hack around this with something like:

```
const myFunction = (function() {
  function myFunction(myparam, {myprop}) {
    // ...
  }

  return function(myparam) {
    return myFunction(myparam, myparam);
  };
}());
```

or even

```
function myFunction(myparam, {myprop}=myparam) {
  // ...
}
```

but both may be considered too hacky.